# App crashes at runtime due to library project resources missing

Tags: java, android, exception, classnotfoundexception, library-project

I've been developing a library that can be seen here: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

I recently created a new project and copied over the Java/XML/Drawables due to the new Android Studio (0.8.14 Beta), Gradle, and SDK Build Tools updates. Suddenly I've run into an issue when I attempt to run the sample project I've created, it had been working fine yesterday.

Here's the exception throw at Runtime when the user clicks one of the buttons in the sample:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/afollestad/materialdialogs/R$color;
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$Builder.<init>(MaterialDialog.java:389)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogssample.MainActivity.showCallbacks(MainActivity.java:143)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogssample.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:24)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogssample.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.afollestad.materialdialogs.R$color" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.afollestad.materialdialogssample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$Builder.<init>(MaterialDialog.java:389)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogssample.MainActivity.showCallbacks(MainActivity.java:143)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogssample.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:24)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogssample.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.afollestad.materialdialogs.R$color
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 15 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

When the class `MaterialDialog` is instantiated, it retrieves resources such as colors and dimensions. For whatever reason, it appears these aren't be transferred to the APK file. I thought it might be a manifest merger issue.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @VenomVendor it's listed in the beginning :) Android Studio 0.8.14 Beta

Comment: Can you try clean & build once.!

Comment: @VenomVendor I've tried that a few times and unfortunately with no success at runtime.

Comment: I imported your repo & tried various gradle config, but throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating yet another project. Not sure what was different the second time o.O

Comment: Try comparing both the projects using beyond compare after removing the build files, if possible let me know the difference which caused the issue.